# Django login() without authenticate()

Tags: django, authentication

I'm failing to understand what does authenticate() and login() are supposed to do. For example, in view like this:

```
class HomeView(FormView):                                                      
    template_name = 'home/index.html'                                          
    form_class = AuthenticationForm                                            
    success_url = '/'                                                          

    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)                                            
    @method_decorator(never_cache)                                             
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):                                       
        return super(HomeView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)                 

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):                                      
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)             
        if 'next' in self.request.GET:                                         
            context['next'] = self.request.GET['next']                         
        return context                                                         

    def form_valid(self, form):                                                
        if form.data['next']:                                                  
            self.success_url = form.data['next']                               
        login(self.request, form.get_user())                                   
        return super(HomeView, self).form_valid(form)
```

I've tested with active and inactive user, it behaves like I don't need authenticate() (ie. I can login if user is active, but not if inactive). Why is it so? Thanx!

Comment: authenticate() sets an attribute on the noting which authentication backend successfully authenticated that user. Documentation is here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in

Comment: Note that AuthenticationForm *calls* authenticate,  hence the name; that's why this code works.

Comment: Thank you @DanielRoseman, that's the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can understand it quickly digging django source code (also with django docs):

[Authenticate](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/backends.py) check for user and password:

```
def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
    UserModel = get_user_model()
    if username is None:
        username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
    try:
        user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
    except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
        # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
        # difference between an existing and a non-existing user (#20760).
        UserModel().set_password(password)
```

[Login](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py):

```
"""
Persist a user id and a backend in the request. This way a user doesn't
have to reauthenticate on every request. Note that data set during
the anonymous session is retained when the user logs in.
"""
```

As you can see, it is not a good idea to login user without authenticate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
authenticate()
```

This will check your password  against the given username/email/whatever if it is valid it will return the user object

```
  login()
```

will create a session id for the user and persist(save session in db/cache/etc backends) the user so that you don't have to authenticate() every time a request is sent by that user.